# How do I get the name of the route namespace within its block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am calling a custom method within a namespaced route.

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :v1 do
  some_custom_method :users
end
```

Within `some_custom_method` I would like to access the `namespace` (`v1`). How?

Comment: Using rake routes will show you the routes that are available but it'll be something like `some_custom_method_v1_users_path`

Comment: To get the complete path of your controller, you can use `controller_path` inside your `some_custom_method`.

Comment: `some_custom_method` is a macro that sets up routes for an API. So, I need access to the namespace to resolve a class that is similarly namespaced. In other words, `some_custom_method` isn't an HTTP method, it's a Ruby method.